# Reuse IMobileBarcodeScanner in cross platform app?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, mvvmcross

I am writing an app using xamarin, mvvmcross, and zxing.net.mobile.  I would like to be able to use an instance of IMobileBarcodeScanner in the portable class library to do the scanning.

The issue I'm running into is that the droid version of IMobileBarcodeScanner requires a context to be passed into the constructor.  I'm guessing we'd need to register the type in the view constructor so we can pass the correct context.

Since there will be multiple views, would I be able to register a different instance of IMobileBarcodeScanner for each view?  Or, could I make the IMobileBarcodeScanner a public property on the view model and set it from the view constructor instead?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways I've worked with barcode scanners in the past.

1. I've launched them as 'new pages' - including using external activities and StartActivityForResult in Android
2. I've treated them as 'normal controls' - a bit like TextEdit fields within the current page.

When doing the first of these, I generally used a pattern similar to the [PictureChooser plugin](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/PictureChooser) - on Android, this accesses the current context using IoC in [MvxAndroidTask](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore.Droid/Platform/MvxAndroidTask.cs)

When doing the second, I treat this purely as a View concern - all the ViewModel needs to provide is an `ICommand` and/or a `string` property which can be bound to the scanned event or to the scanned text.